# String#method vs String#method() in ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby,  we have Classes on which we run methods. example `class.methodName`. Now, I am coming from PHP world where method == function and should have parenthesis. In, Ruby. I have noticed. both work & render the same result:

1. Without parens:

   ```
   "Gaurish".reverse  # => "hsiruaG"
   ```
2. With parens:

   ```
   "Gaurish".reverse() # => "hsiruaG"
   ```

Are both the same. If yes, then which one should we use. If not, then what's the difference?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the same. Method calls without empty parentheses are more standard in Ruby.

Comment: And what about `super` vs. `super()` difference?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that both expressions are almost the same. The longer, is that there are some differences:

1. First of all there are some methods which are almost always called without parentheses, even with arguments, e.g. `puts` - its argument is rarely wrapped by parentheses. The same is with methods which provide access to instance variables, like `person.name` and similar.
2. If you have many methods chained, then the argument-less methods usually won't have parentheses, while those with arguments, will have. 
   E.g. `"aaaabc".squeeze.sub(/ab/,"c").upcase`
3. If there are nested method calls which are not called on objects, the arguments of theme should be wrapped by parentheses to avoid confusion, e.g. `puts rand 5` - even if it works, it might be hard to figure out what happens here, so the preferred style is `puts rand(5)`.
4. The previous rule is not applied to operators (because they are called on objects), so will see calls such as `puts "abc" * 5` quite often. Nothing strange here - operators have higher priorities than regular method calls, so it should be quite easy to figure out what happens in such situation (in the example given, the string will be multiplied first and then passed to `pust`.
5. When we write `something = 5` in the context of a method, there might be a confusion if we are calling a method (something=(value)) or assigning a value to a variable. Using parentheses would be awkward in this case, so the usual solution when we wish to call a method is to write `self` in front of the method name, e.g. `self.something = 5`.
6. A similar situation happens when we call a getter or any other method without paremeters in the context of a class method, e.g. `name` (without `self`). In such a case there are two options: the first described above (`self.name`) and the second where we place parentheses after to method name (`name()`). Both are preferred over the bare method name.
7. And the last but not the least - the methods without arguments are usually called without parentheses, with one *important exception* - when you call `super` without arguments in a method that accepts arguments, these arguments will be passed to that call. Sometimes it is not desired, so in this case the parentheses are obligatory, i.e. `super()` will not pass the arguments.

Comment: Nice answer. One other time there's a difference is if there's a local variable and a method with the same name. Using the name without `()` will use the variable, using it with `()` will use the method.

Comment: Yes, I added this case - p. 6.

Answer (score 2):

`()` are optional.  Whatever you find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, booth are the same. Also you don't need to wrap parameters with parens, so:

```
puts "lalala"
puts("lalala")

"alla".gsub 'la', 'a'
"alla".gsub('la', 'a')
```

Is the same. I prefer the version without parens, but sometimes if you chain method calling they are needed. Parens also are needed when you want serve return value of method thet take arguments as parameter of other method, i.e.:

```
link_to I18n.translate('some text'), root_path
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same but the syntax with parentesis is to be prefered if you have parameters to your method. Here is an example:

```
def foo x
  ...
end


foo a * 3
```

What will happen? Will foo be called with a and then the result be mutliplied by 3 or vice versa. This could be a little confusing.
Also in irb for instance you get a warning : "Parantesize arguments for future uses."

For zero parameter methods, both syntaxes are valid and usually not using parathesis does not cause that much confusion, I guess.

Comment: so add parenthesis if there are arguments. skip them, if method has no arguments?