# "include? foo && true" produces unexpected (false) result

Tags: ruby, syntax

Consider:

```
foo = :bar
```

and:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? foo
=> true
```

However,

```
[:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? foo && true
=> false
```

and

```
([:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? foo) && true
=> true
```

Why does the first format not work? Does Ruby evaluate `foo && true` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` has high precedence. Essentially the statement becomes

```
[:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? (foo && true)
```

You can try the `and` operator which has a lower precedence:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? foo and true
```

which is the same as

```
([:a, :b, :c, :bar].include? foo) && true
```

Comment: I kept reading around that `and` isn't a good idea. Should I stick to parentheses?

Comment: I personally prefer the parentheses because it makes the code much more clearer and explicit IMO - I don't have to worry about details such as operator precedence. Also see this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/342475/276949

Comment: Interesting - so according to the SO answer you referenced, I'm not following the "Ruby way" if I'm sticking to the Rails guides with all of those methods not using parentheses? e.g. `f.text_field :name`? Sorry, this is kind of unrelated but I'm curious.

Comment: The community style-guide for rails has specific set of rules: "Omit parentheses around parameters for methods that are part of an internal DSL (e.g. Rake, Rails, RSpec), methods that have "keyword" status in Ruby (e.g. attr_reader, puts) and attribute access methods. **Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations.**" https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MartinKonecny, I've also noticed that I was using the `include?` method without parentheses which was creating ambiguity. A better approach would be to do:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :bar].include?(foo) && true
=> true
```