# Sublime Text generate wrong "form_for" tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

I'm new with RoR, anytime when I used code snipet on Sublime Text to generate a "form_for" tag, the result is:

```html
<% form_for @model do |f| -%>

  <% end -%>
```

But as I know, it should be

```html
<%= form_for (@message) do |f| %>
  <% end %>
```

hope to receive help from you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, you can call a method and pass in the arguments with or without the (parentheses). It is generally considered [better Ruby coding practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby) to leave them out, which is why the Sublime Text snippet is leaving them off. Also, the snippet expects you to replace `@model` with whatever model instance you are working with in the particular form.