# In Ruby, how can you pass more than one hash to a method, without parentheses?

Tags: ruby, arguments, parentheses

In Ruby, how can one pass more than one hash to a method, without parentheses?

For example

```
def abc x,y
end
```

`abc {4,5},{6,4}` <-- `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'`

Comment: if anybody votes to close this, please comment why. It's only one line and I have not given an example, but I think it's very self explanatory

Comment: @maxpleaner not really because ruby is quite complex, and I wouldn't immediately rule out that there is a way to pass multiple hashes just because I can't see a way. And there are keyword arguments (which I didn't know much about), which makes it more complex

Comment: Also, saying `obj.m x, y` can qualify as "passing more than one hash to a method". So are you talking about passing multiple hashes? Multiple hashes as hash literals? A mix of both?

Comment: @muistooshort  I hadn't thought of that. From what you're saying, it looks like you can pass multiple hashes. i'll try that

Comment: Also also, keyword arguments can also be involved when you say `h = { a: 'a' }; m h` when you `def m(a:)`. And multiple hash literals can be `m { k: v }, k2: v2, k3: v3` (this variation pops up in Rails a fair bit when there are multiple options hashes for a form builder method). So you need to be a lot clearer about what you're asking as @maxpleaner notes.

Comment: @muistooshort  yeah I mentioned the keyword arguments thing in my answer . but well spotted re non-literal hash I hadn't spotted that

Comment: @muistooshort you can post that as an answer

Comment: @barlop maybe you find the time to edit / clarify your question in regard to the comments so we can try to reopen it.

Comment: @Stefan i've just adjusted the question and added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mu points out that you can pass multiple hashes without parentheses, if you pass them in as non-literals i.e. as variables.

But other than that, so, for literal hashes,

You do(need parentheses to pass multiple literal hashes), unless you are passing keyword arguments.. You can pass multiple keyword arguments without parentheses.

a keyword argument would be when the parameters of the method include a colon like e.g. `def blah x:, y:`  then you can call with `blah y:2,x:3` . Sometimes you have to look at the parameter(s) to see if an argument is a keyword argument, e.g. if you have a method called with abc x:3
 then that might be `def abc x:`  in which case you called it with a keyword argument.  Or it might be `def abc x` in which case you called it with a hash, omitting the {}.

When I say keyword argument, I don't mean a hash..  and vice versa, when I say hash I mean not a keyword argument.

When a call is without parentheses, you can only pass one hash and that hash has to be the last argument.  And you can skip the {} around it.

note- I'm no expert, but as to a related question of whether a keyword argument is a type of hash,   from what I understand, as of writing, pre ruby 3, they are, but there is a proposal for ruby 3 to have 'real' keyword arguments that are distinct from hashes https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14183

a keyword argument can't be multi-valued.

also, a hash can be automatically converted to a keyword argument. (e.g. if a method is defined with a parameter that is a keyword argument, you can pass a hash in e.g. `{x:"a"}`  , that x being a symbol, and that hash will be converted to a keyword argument `x:"a"` (that x being a parameter name).

I'll add a point regarding blocks and parentheses, because a block done with {} does look a little bit like a hash though is not a hash. And a block can have some influence on whether parentheses are needed.

If you see `abc {}`, that {} is a block not a hash, and blocks don't count as an argument. Hence that call works for `def abc` but not for `def abc x` where one would get an error related to number of arguments passed.

even when passing a block after some other arguments, there should be no comma before the block, and if a block done with {} follows some arguments, you need parentheses, but if a block done with `do .. end` follows some arguments, you don't need parentheses

it is suggested that one use parentheses when one has multiple arguments, unless it's a DSL(domain specific language). [Do you leave parentheses in or out in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby)